# Will overclocking an Intel CPU also increase the performance of the iGPU (OBS Quick Sync)?

Tags: intel-graphics, overclocking, intel-core-i7, integrated-graphics

I'm using Quick Sync with OBS and am wondering whether it might be beneficial to overclock the CPU (ratio/vcore).

If not the CPU (ratio/vcore), is there anything I can overclock that will increase Quick Sync performance?

I have an i7 4790k.

Comment: Is there a way to observe iGPU usage? As far as I know, it's an independent processor and it's usage isn't reflected in the task manager.

Comment: Any way to increase the performance of the iGPU?

Comment: Looks like the iGPU overclocks automatically if the VCore of the CPU is increased. http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/275461-29-review-overclocked-intel-3000-graphics-performance

Comment: http://linustechtips.com/main/topic/113017-intel-3570k-igpu-overclocking/#entry1510708 - The benchmark done there depicts a 5fps increase on the overclocked iGPU. I'd hardly call that nothing.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not trying to shoo you away here but you had made some false assumptions and I wanted to steer the conversation in the right direction.

Comment: Well I already feel like you did that.  So I will just take my ball and go home.   I like my shiny ball.

Answer (score 2):

No, you need to overclock your iGPU to get a performance increase.

Quick Sync uses your iGPU, which also gets faster when you overclock said GPU.
The performance gain is very minimal though.

If you want to monitor/overclock the iGPU, you can use MSI Afterburner.

Best of luck!

Comment: I'd prefer a solution that utilizes the BIOS instead of another set of software. Nothing against MSI Afterburner - it's awesome and I've used it on many PCs but my GPU right now benefits more from using the included ASUS GPU Tweak (same functionality as MSI-A).

Comment: BIOS is my preferred method too :) If you have a NVENC enabled GPU, you could easily set your OBS to that by the way!

Comment: Ya that would be an option but I have a 390x. More often than not I'm maxing out the GPU while the CPU isn't getting hit very hard so leveraging the extra unused performance there seems to be more effective in my situation.